# Share dataset between two azureml environnement

Tags: python, dataset, jupyter, azure-machine-learning-service

a friend have sent me a python3 notebook with his dataset to validate his notebook.

but when i try to use his dataset on my azureml workspace i have an error saying that the dataset does not exist

he sent me his datset code :

```
from azureml import Workspace

ws = Workspace(
    workspace_id='toto',
    authorization_token='titi',
    endpoint='https://studioapi.azureml.net'
)
ds = ws.datasets['mini.csv00']
frame = ds.to_dataframe()

frame
```

when i try to use it i have a :

```
ndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5f41120e38e4> in <module>()
----> 1 ds = ws.datasets['mini.csv00']
      2 frame = ds.to_dataframe()
      3 
      4 frame

/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azureml/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, index)
    461                     return self._create_dataset(dataset)
    462 
--> 463         raise IndexError('A data set named "{}" does not exist'.format(index))
    464 
    465     def add_from_dataframe(self, dataframe, data_type_id, name, description):

IndexError: A data set named "mini.csv00" does not exist
```

error ...

But when i try it on my computer jupyter it works.
Any ideas ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Hi @user462794, According to the error message, the first line of your code is the dataset lookup. Did you create a new workspace object using your friend's workspace id/auth token? ("ws" will be defined by default in an AML Studio notebook, but it will point to your own workspace, not your friend's.) If so, what datasets are listed when you run the following: `print([ds.name for ds in ws.user_datasets])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using Jupyter notebook on AzureML to do the experiment. In that case the `'mini.csv00'` should be in your experiments with `workspace_id='toto'`.

Create a new experiment in your workspace named toto and put the dataset into it first. Then open the dataset using 'open in a new Notebook'.

[image]

Comment: i would like to use it without the pain to have to upload it is this possible ?

Comment: It's impossible to use a dataset uploaded to a different workSpace. If you wish to do that, upload the dataset to a separate blob or a web space and access it via a http request.